# How to move only a vertex at a time of an empty object with an image sequence attached

Tags: animation, camera, image

I added a background image sequence by adding an “empty” to the scene in blender 2.8. Now,I want to match the empty where I have attached the images to the same position of the camera,but I see that I can't move the single vertex of the square. When I move one vertex,all the vertices move together. Is there a way to move only one vertex at a time ? in this way I will be easier to match perfectly the empty's square with the camera's square. thanks.

[image: a]

Comment: There isn't since it would stretch the image. You can grab, scale and rotate though.

Comment: with G,R,S I'm not able to match perfectly the empty with the camera...

Comment: That only works if the camera has the same focal length and aspect ratio as the one that took the picture.

Comment: I don't know what's the focal lenght and aspect ratio of the camera that tooks the picture because it comes from a movie.

Comment: That's why you need camera/motion tracking that uses a solver to determine these properties.

Comment: I have already done this step. I've tracked the movements of the real camera with the voodoo tracker and then I've imported these movements in blender. now if I move the camera it makes the same movements of the real one. but i still don't know what's the original focal lenght and aspect ratio. i tried to guess and I put 23.6mm as focal lenght

Comment: Blender's own tracker would be more suitable because it allows to refine your initial estimate. Anyway is there a specific reason why you try to align the background image with the scene? You are aware that this won't be visible in render? For combining footage you would need to work in the compositor. See for refine: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/movie_clip/tracking/clip/editing/solve.html?highlight=refine

Comment: Voodoo tracker certainly also refines the values internally, not sure if you get to see these afterwards though.

Comment: I'm trying to align the background images to the objects on the scene because I need to have a lot of reference images to pose the characters. I want that the characters will make the same movements of the actors in the original movie.

Comment: How about using fSpy?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your reference image to align with the camera, setup the camera to use a background image.

In 2.80 Background Image options have been added to the camera, this allows you to keep the image aligned with the camera view even if you move the camera.

[image: camera background image settings]

To ensure the image fills the camera view you need to set the render resultion to match the aspect ratio of the reference image.